# How can I configure Dragon NaturallySpeaking so that spelling a voice command doesn't execute the command?

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

How can I configure Dragon NaturallySpeaking so that spelling a voice command doesn't execute the command?

For example, I have the voice command named `cut`, but when I spell `cut` I do not want the voice command to be executed:

[image]

[image]

Comment: First time I hear of this bug. I'd post this on an speech recognition forum, not here.

Comment: @user99572isfine thanks I'll do. The issue is that speech recognition forum typically don't provide any dump of their forum, so if one day it disappears we are screwed (e.g. http://www.speechcomputing.com). The wayback machine may save a few links but not everything. Old posts on http://knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/index.cfm have issues (attachments are no longer accessible) That's why I prefer to also post on Stack Exchange (even though questions with 0 upvote and 0 answer are automatically deleted).

Comment: The bug is interesting, I just don't have time to do any digging as I sometimes do. You'll get an answer on KnowBrainer Forum sooner.